# Issue playing MIDIs

Tags: 21.04, midi

I have installed both Timidity and FluidSynth, however `aconnect -o` still returns:

```
client 14: 'Midi Through' [type=kernel]
    0 'Midi Through Port-0'
```

which is of no use to me, since I don't have any midi-dedicated hardware.

How do I make FluidSynth and Timidity appear in that list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Qsynth has to be actively running to use FluidSynth.